# What kind of pronoun is "her" in "without her trying"?

Tags: pronouns

In Bruno Mars' song, "Her hair falls perfectly without **her** trying", is the *her* in bold an object pronoun or subject pronoun?

Comment: The pronoun can't be subjective because non-finite _ing_ clauses don't take subjective case pronoun subjects. "Her" is actually strictly speaking ambiguous between genitive (possessive) and accusative (objective) case. The ambiguity arises because the 3rd person feminine genitive and accusative pronouns are identical, so it's impossible to tell which case the pronoun actually belongs to.

Comment: It's an ***ambiguous*** reference that wouldn't arise if she'd happened to be male - in which case you could use either *...without **him** trying* or *...without **his** trying* (not that it would make any difference to the *meaning*, whichever stylistic choice you made there).

Comment: That is a possessive pronoun used with a gerund. Third person possessive for a feminine case is her. Her leaving the school was sad. compare: His leaving the school was sad. HIm leaving the school was bad.

Answer (score 2):

> *Her hair falls perfectly without* [*her trying*].

"Her" is strictly speaking ambiguous between genitive and accusative case, with the latter being informal style.

However, both forms of the 3rd person feminine pronoun are identical, so it's impossible to tell which case the pronoun actually belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of the sentence is "her *hair*", and not 'her', so the second instance is an *object* pronoun. Note that while the first use of 'her' is a *possessive* pronoun, the second is not.

Consider as a comparable example:

> His car rolled away without him.

In this case, 'his car' is the subject and 'him' is the object.

Comment: Would it? "Her hair falls perfectly without her" doesn't make much sense to me. You could omit the 2nd her and it would make more sense. "Her hair falls perfectly without trying."

Comment: @Jontia It makes some sense - like "I can do this myself without you helping" - you could omit the final word. But your suggestion is definitely wrong - it sounds like the hair is trying, not her. Does hair consciously try to fall? Don't think so.

Comment: Defiantly agree with the helping example. I just don't think the OP's sentence fits the same mould. "Her hair falls perfectly without effort" doesn't imply that the hair is making effort. Trying doesn't fit the pattern as well, but then it isn't the word I would chose if trying to omit "her".

Comment: @lambie but with no mention of "her" (only "her hair") who is doing the trying in your example? The hair?

Comment: I miswrote my example: "Her hair falls perfectly without her trying." implies: "Her hair falls perfectly without her trying [to make it fall perfectly]".

Answer (score 0):

> Her hair falls perfectly without **her** trying.

I agree with @Lambie that *her trying* is a **possessive-gerund** pair.

Depending on what we want to focus on when we write, we choose either the **possessive-gerund** pair or the **objective-present participle** pair.

[grammarbook](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/pronouns/expressing-possession-of-gerunds/) explains further.

When interpreting a sentence, our choice could be limited by the sentence structure.

In OP's example, the gerund *trying* is preceded by the possessive noun *her*, and the focus is on the action, 'her **trying**'.

On the other hand, if the objective *her* is used, the focus would be on the pronoun *her*.  *trying* would be a present participle acting as an adjective modifying *her*.  We test the clause by removing the adjective.

> Her hair falls perfectly without **her**.

I would not be able to interpret this clause.

The sentence structure of OP's question does not permit this interpretation.

Answer (score -2):

'**Her** hair falls perfectly without **her** trying.'

Here the first **her** is a possessive adjective. The second **her** can work as an object pronoun.

Let's change the gender. The sentence would be '**His** hair falls perfectly without **his**/**him** trying.

She loves her cat. (She-pronoun, her-adjective,)

Her hair is beautiful. (her- adjective)

The cat is hers. (hers-pronoun)

I phoned her. ('Her' is the object pronoun)

She phoned me. ('She' is the subject pronoun)

subject- she, object- her

subject- I, object- me

Comment: The OP asked about the _second_ occurrence of _her_.

Comment: Yes, but in the OP's example the pronoun is located in a subordinate clause "her trying", so it can only be either a genitive (possessive) pronoun or an accusative (objective) one.

Comment: If the person is a male, then the sentence will be ' hair falls perfectly without / trying'. Am I right?

Comment: Well done; your English is accurate, but the names of how it works are not.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you for your contribution to my comment.

Comment: @Kate Bunting The first 'her' is a possessive adjective. The second 'her' can be used as the possessive form or the objective form.

Comment: @MohammadFarukhAhmad Yes, you are right. The ambiguity occurs only with the female pronoun, "her" being both genitive and accusative.  With other persons, there are distinct forms ("my/me"; "your/ you; "his/him" etc.).